# Derivative of the function $x^2e^{-x^2}$

Tags: calculus

Can someone please help me with the following question.

> Find the derivatives (if they exist) of the function $f(x) = x^2e^{-x^2}$ if $|x|$ less than or equal to $1$ and $f(x) = \dfrac 1 e$ if $|x|$ is less than $1$.

Comment: Use the product rule. The second function is just a constant so its derivative is $0$.

Comment: Is this what you meant for the function ?

Comment: You have to do the case $|x|=1$ separately.  Presumably one of the two cases should be $|x| greater than $1$, right?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* Do you know the product rule? If you let $y=f(x)g(x),$ then we have that $$\mathrm d y=f(x)\mathrm d g(x)+g(x)\mathrm d f(x).$$ Use this for the first. For the second, note that it doesn't depend on $x$ in an interesting way. Thus, its differential is null.

Answer (score 1):

$$f'(x)=( 2x e^{ -x^2 }-2x^3 e^{ -x^2 })=2x e^{ -x^2 }( 1-x^2 )$$

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=x^2e^{-x^2}$$
Substitute $u=x^2$:
$$f(u)=ue^{-u}$$
$$f'(x)=\dfrac {df}{dx}=\dfrac {df}{du}\dfrac {du}{dx}=2x \dfrac {df}{du}$$
$$\dfrac {df}{du}=e^{-u}-ue^{-u}$$
Therefore:
$$f'(x)=2x(e^{-u}-ue^{-u})=2x(e^{-x^2}-x^2e^{-x^2})$$
$$f'(x)=2xe^{-x^2}(1-x^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

Logarithmic differentiation makes life easier for this kind of problema
$$f(x)=x^2e^{-x^2}\implies \log(f(x))=2\log(x)-x^2$$ Differentiate both sides
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac 2x -2x=\frac {2(1-x^2)}x$$
$$f'(x)=f(x) \times \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}= x^2e^{-x^2}\times \frac {2(1-x^2)}x$$ Simplify